# How would you say in Spanish, "I'm in the middle of doing something?"

Tags: traducción, expresiones

In the context of say, when someone calls you and asks you to do something, and in turn you say "I'm actually in the middle of doing something else." I tried googling "estoy en el medio de" and "estoy en el proceso de." I got a few results from the latter, nothing from the former.

Comment: estar liado con hacer algo, which means busy but also in the middle of.

Comment: ... and when you are really busy, you can say "[estoy más liado que la pata de un romano](https://lahistoriaheredada.com/curiosidades-iv/)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation to say you are busy is practically literal, but without the article before middle:

- Estoy en medio de una tarea

> José, ***estoy en medio de una tarea*** importante y no puedo demorarme. ¿Podemos vernos por la tarde?

As a general rule, in these cases, the article is used when it is something quantifiable, measurable or has a beginning and an end:

- Estoy en **el** medio **del** tren
- Estoy en **el** centro de **la** habitación

Or if the person asking the question knows in advance what the activity to be carried out is and wants to know what phase you are in, the answer would be:

- Estoy en **el** medio de **la** tarea

(Although I would never use this form, it doesn't sound very common).

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to say what you are doing, you can say:

- Estoy ocupado
- No es un buen momento

If you want to say what you are doing (for example, doing the laundry, you usually say it directly:

- Estoy (ocupado) haciendo la colada

I am not aware of any expression that uses a more literal translation of "in the middle of": neither "en el medio de" or "en proceso de" sound natural. If you want it to sound less unwilling, you usually emphasize that it is a coincidence that you are busy and that you will do it later:

- Justo ahora estoy haciendo la colada, pero luego te ayudo.

Answer (score 2):

Spanish is a very rich language with a lot of regional variations. In my regional dialect we would just say:

- Ahora no puedo, estoy ocupado --> (literally: I can't [help you] right now, I am busy [no need to specify you are doing something else])

Answer (score 2):

Al menos en Español de España tenemos una expresión muy acorde a esa situación, de uso muy común y coloquial que deja claro que en ese momento concreto estas involucrado en un tipo de actividad que te impide de manera razonada ó incluso imposible, temporalmente, dejarla en el instante para hacer ó realizar aquella otra cosa que en ese momento te demandan o ha surgido, ya que se sobrentiende que es una llamada imprevista ó por sorpresa en la que se solicita que se cambie una actividad por otra.

Así nosotros utilizamos la expresión "Me pillas". Lo bueno de esta expresión es que puedes añadir a la expresión "en medio de"/"Me pillas en medio de", o simplemente obviarlo si así lo estimas y decir simplemente "Me pillas". Extendido en el tiempo siempre se sobrentiende.

Imaginemos varias situaciones;

- Una llamada telefónica - Hola Juan, P. ¿Vienes a jugar a las cartas?. R. Lo siento, me pillas haciendo un pastel.
- P. ¿Os venid a comer con nosotros?. R. Nos pillas poniendo la mesa, precisamente hoy tenemos visita.

*Normalmente se utiliza "Me pillas" + la tarea que estas realizando en ese instante*.

- **Demanda en el tiempo**
- P. ¿Rosario, podrías encargarte esta tarde de ir a recoger a Don Julián?. R. Lo siento Patricio pero me pillas conduciendo hacia Lisboa, o "me pillas" en el tren hacia Lisboa, avión...
  (La otra persona entenderá que es imposible materialmente).
- Este fin de semana vamos a la nieve, P. ¿nos vemos allí?. R. Vaya, me pillas con el coche en el taller.

Espero te haya ayudado.

Diego M.